# Select not null column in full join postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
with current_exclusive as(
        select id_station, area_type, 
    count(*) as total_entries
    from c1169.data_cashier
    where id_station IN(2439,2441,2443,2445,2447,2449) and date >= '2017-10-30' and date <= '2017-12-30' 
    group by id_station, area_type
), current_table as(
        select id_station, area_type, 
    sum(total_time) filter (where previous_status = 1) as total_time
    from c1169.data_table
    where id_station IN(2439,2441,2443,2445,2447,2449) and date >= '2017-10-30' and date < '2017-12-30' 
    group by id_station, area_type
), current_cashier as(
        select id_station, area_type, 
    sum(1) as total_transactions
    from c1169.data_cashier
    where id_station IN(2439,2441,2443,2445,2447,2449) and date >= '2017-10-30' and date < '2017-12-30' 
    group by id_station, area_type
)
select *
from current_exclusive
full join current_table on current_exclusive.id_station = current_table.id_station and current_exclusive.area_type = current_table.area_type
full join current_cashier on current_exclusive.id_station = current_cashier.id_station and current_exclusive.area_type = current_cashier.area_type
```

and the result is:
[image]

but my expected result is:

[image]

Are there any way to select * and show the expected result? Because when I do full join then id_station and area_type can be null in some tables, so it very hard to choose which column is not null. 
Like: `select case id_station is not null then id_station else id_station1 end`, but I have up to 10 tables so can not do in select case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `USING`, per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

> USING ( join_column [, ...] )
>
> A clause of the form USING ( a, b, ... ) is shorthand for ON left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b .... Also, USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output, not both.

```
select *
from current_exclusive
full join current_table using (id_station, area_type)
full join current_cashier using (id_station, area_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish anything if you insist on using `select *`, since you are getting the values from different tables.

The option you have is to include a `COALESCE` block which gives you the first `non-null` value from the list of columns.

So, you could use.

```
select COALESCE( current_exclusive.id_station, current_table.id_station, current_cashier.id_station ) as id_station , 
COALESCE( current_exclusive.area_type , current_table.area_type, current_cashier.area_type ) as area_type ,.....
...
from current_exclusive
full join current_table..
...
```